# Best practices for handling Angular4 Http Obserable responses

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have experience writing C# and Angular1 code, but Angular2+ and RxJs are new to me.

I've just written an Angular4 login component and I feel like I've written a code smell by caching the result of the login method in the map function of the observable.

I have an AuthenticationService which the LoginComponent calls login on:

```
  login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
return this.http
  .post('/api/users/login', { username: username, password: password })
  .map((response: Response) => {

    let loginResult = response.json();
    this.user = loginResult.user as User

    localStorage.setItem(tokenStorageName, loginResult.token);

    return this.user;
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

}

It feels strange to save state in the map function because as far as I'm aware that should just be a translation function. I want to cache the user and token which come back from the login result so that I don't have to make another service call if I want the users data.

Here is the logic of the login component:

```
  login() {
this.isLoading = true;
this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
  .subscribe(
  result => {
    let returnUrl = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams['returnUrl'] || '/'
    this.router.navigate([returnUrl]);
  }, error => {
    if (error != null && error.code == unauthorizedCode) {
      this.error = 'Username or password incorrect';
    }
    else {
      this.error = 'Error logging in';
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
  });
```

It also doesn't feel right for the LoginComponent to call setUser on the AuthenticationService or a UserCache.

Can someone give me some advice into best practices here please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Todd Motto gave a good example via Twitter:

https://twitter.com/toddmotto/status/865531009638440961

"This is where a single state store comes in really handy - you could finish your code with:
.do(next => /* do something with this value */)"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
    let o = this.http
        .post('/api/users/login', { username: username, password: password})
    //uncomment if you have multiple subscribers, otherwise http request is executed multiple times
        //.share()
    ;

    o.subscribe(
        (response: Response) => {
            this.user = loginResult.user as User;
            localStorage.setItem(tokenStorageName, loginResult.token);
        },
        (response: Response) => this.handleError(response)
    );

    return o.map(response: Response =>  response.json());
}
```

Comment: Nice idea, is share() generally considered to do or does it break some of the principles of observables? I suppose an alternative approach would be to put a UsersService in between the LoginComponent and the AuthenticationService which resolves the observables from the AuthenticationService and does the caching there. But this seems a bit over the top?

Comment: Please see RxJs documentation regarding both solutions (`do()` and `share()`): https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md

Comment: Sorry, can edit comments only for 5 mins...

In my case, I do `showLoader()` for each request. All CRUD resources have shared success and error handlers. But each CRUD component could have own success and error handler. If I `subscribe()` twice (for `shared` and `specific` logic), at least `showLoader()` is executed twice.

For sure I could code with multiple `do()`'s, but why should I restrict myself?

Comment: Or I do not understand something in this life :)